# C++ IO/Multiplexed TCP Server and POSIX Threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, select, tcp

I must develop a simple C++ command line client/server chat application. This application must provide a basic multiple two-partecipants chat-room implementation. Is it possible to combine IO/Multiplexing (select() syscall) with POSIX threads?
I mean I want to create a TCP server which handles multiple clients with select() and when a client wants to chat with another one  the servewr creates a separate thread , that uses IO/Multiplexing (select() syscall)  , to handle the communication between the two clients.
Is this a good idea? How could I do otherwise?

Comment: It's possible to combine the methods, but not really needed and would only complicate things.  Combining the methods is usually done when you have many more connections, where you have a few threads each handling a set of connections. if you have only a few connections, and they need to communicate with each other, I recommend the multiplexing approach.

Comment: The problem is that I'm doing it for a network programming exam and the use of both threads and select is explicitly required.

Comment: Using `select()` together with threads should pose no particular problems, except that closing a file descriptor in one thread that is part of a select in another produces an undefined outcome and I/O on descriptors shared between threads should (probably, I do not know if these operations are always atomic) be guarded by mutexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A crude attempt at an architecture...

Structure your application as two sets of threads (a set might be composed of just one thread).

One set minds the TCP connections, each TCP connection is assigned to one of the threads in the set, the thread just runs forever polling the connections assigned to it (incoming messages) and polling a (per-thread) from-logic queue (outgoing messages)

The other set minds the logic/session. Each session is assigned to a specific thread. Each thread just runs forever polling the (per-thread) from-network queue (incoming messages).

The network thread-set, receives messages and post them to the right logic queue [assumes there's a way of mapping connections to internal logic sessions]. It polls its from-logic queue to get the outgoing messages and send them.

The number of network threads is bound, and it does not depend on the number of connections.

The logic thread-set, receives requests from the network in its queue and handles them within a given session state and (perhaps) post back messages to the be sent out (sent out by the network threads)

The number of logic threads is bound, and it does not depend on the number of sessions.

Comment: This is a good idea, I guess that i can use this structure but how can I add support to other commands like "list users on the server" , "handle logout"?

Comment: @GiorgioGambino, I guess that when you receive an incoming message, it will be dispatched to different event handler methods/functions running within the logic thread set for different commands.